# Monad vs Applicative in the case of Reader resp. ((->) a)

Tags: haskell, monads

In Haskell, what does the monad instance of functions give over just applicative? Looking at their implementations, they seem almost identical:

```
(<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
(>>=) f g x = g (f x) x
```

Is there anything you can do with `>>=` that you can't do with just `<*>`?

Comment: I believe there is no difference, in the case of `((->) a)` and `Reader` (which are the same thing), between what the `Applicative` and `Monad` interfaces allow. This is different from most types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are equivalent in power for the function instance: `flip f <*> g  ==  g >>= f`. This is not true for most types that are instances of Monad though.

It's a little more clear if we compare `<*>` and `=<<` (which is `flip (>>=)`) specialized to the `((->) r)` instance:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
   -- Specialized to ((->) r):
(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b

(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
   -- Specialized to ((->) r):
(=<<) :: (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
```